# Remove variables appended to JS File

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

My Joomla installation loads Jquery as follows

```
/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js?74a9f5d23561aa584c363ede5bfbfad6
```

The value 74a9f5d23561aa584c363ede5bfbfad6 keeps changing and hence caching in not optimized

How can I remove this data?

Want only this file to load /media/jui/js/jquery.min.js

Comment: Cross-posted by different user @ https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/30363/12352